# How to place play image in the middle of the teal square?

Tags: css, css-position

How would this be done? https://jsfiddle.net/mLwcyj9u/

Can you help me?

I am trying to place the play image in the middle of the teal square.

That is all I am trying to do.

Place the play image inside the teal square.

Those are all the details.

That is everything.

I provided a snippet below.

```css
.channel-tile {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 180px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  background: #2E2E2E;
  position: relative;
}

.channel-tile__image-area {
  width: 180px;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.channel-tile__artwork {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 0;
  background: teal;
}

.cover {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 9px solid blue;
  background: transparent;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.cover::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 27px solid blue;
  transform: translateX(4px);
}
```

```html
<div class="channel-tile">
  <div class="channel-tile__image-area">
    <span class="channel-tile__artwork"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cover">
</div>
```

Comment: Simple, place your `.cover` element inside the `-area` and in CSS use position absolute (etc) just like you did for `__artwork`.

Comment: I don't understand, the play image keeps getting messed up.

Comment: see the answer below then. I just moved `<div class="cover"` into `-area` and added the same "absolute centering styles" like the ones you had for `__artwork`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, place your `.cover` element inside the `-area` and in CSS use position absolute (etc) just like you did for `__artwork`.

```css
.channel-tile {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 180px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  background: #2E2E2E;
  position: relative;
}

.channel-tile__image-area {
  width: 180px;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.channel-tile__artwork {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 0;
  background: teal;
}

.cover {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 9px solid blue;
  background: transparent;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.cover::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 27px solid blue;
  transform: translateX(4px);
}
```

```html
<div class="channel-tile">
  <div class="channel-tile__image-area">
    <span class="channel-tile__artwork"></span>
    <div class="cover"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Avoid using `float`. Use `flex` instead.